# What is the benefit of focusing on the "body" textarea when clicking on a question preview?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, editor

Maybe I'm weird, but I seem to run into this all the time when creating questions.

Say I'm typing a long question, and I'm proof-reading it and I click or double-click some of the text in the preview as I'm reading, the focus jumps to the **body** textarea of the editor.

I find this annoying and unexpected (*well, expected now that I've experienced it so much* :-P).

**What is the benefit of scrolling back to the input?**

[image]

I suppose an equally good question is:

> Why the heck do you have to click when reviewing your post?"

And I don't really have an answer for that, I just do... :-)

Comment: Because people were thinking that clicking on the preview would allow them to edit where they had clicked.

Comment: I want to say there was even a feature request to make it behave this way that got a lot of attention but I can only find this [feature request that specifically requested the cursor go where they clicked in the preview](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292348/when-create-edit-answer-question-click-preview-section-show-mouse-carret-at-app).

Comment: Seems like a good way to find the right spot I want to edit in a long post tbh- for example let's say I wrote 10 example SQLs and one of them had 3 spaces before the select rather than 4, so the whole thing is not code formatted. The preview would show that easily and clicking would take me to where I can fix the problem. Scanning a long post looking for which one of 10 sqls had just 3 spaces at the start rather than 4 would be pretty hard

Comment: Maybe learn to click less, your carpal tunnels will thank you for it when you're 50 :)